# Alien invasion movie where the protagonist is invisible to the aliens

Tags: identify-this-movie

Details of what I remember, some of it could be off:

- I saw this movie on TV at around 2009.
- It's a horror-ish small-scale-alien-invasion movie. I believe abduction was involved (for once they weren't trying to blow up national monuments). It is not an action movie.
- It's *not* a found footage film as is popular in this genre.
- The aliens were short and green with large heads, more or less the classic look.
- The humans involved are a group of ~5 friends in their late 20s or in their 30s.
- I believe the humans travel to find the aliens for some reason, and not the usual case where aliens pick a group and abduct them.
- There was one female in the group whose either her name or her actress's name was Hope.
- What I would call the main protagonist was a male, one of the group, who for some reason is invisible to the aliens. This was a key subject in the movie.
- There was a scene where the aliens patrol at night with hand-held weapons in a grassy area and passed right next to him without noticing.
- A good portion of the movie happened in a house, where eventually the group had to hide in the basement. The upper part of the house was obliterated thereafter either by the aliens or by the group as a trap for the invading aliens.
- I believe there was a cage in the house with the sheriff, or his deputy in it.
- One of the humans was severely burnt, and at the end of the movie his body was brought back to the doorstep of his parent's house (such a bad judgment call).

It was not a blockbuster, but not a joke low-budget movie either. Could be that it was straight-to-TV. And it's not The Darkest Hour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you may be looking for the 2006 movie **[Altered](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0457275/)**.

It's been a while since I've seen it but the Aliens are short, green with razor sharp teeth. There is indeed a character called Hope. Also, the sheriff in the film is restrained at one point, though I can't remember him being in a cage.

**Possible Spoiler**:

> A building is blown up while the Alien ship is hovering directly above. I do believe right at the end a burnt body (*from the explosion*) is left on someone's doorstep.

**Synopsis**:

> After a chance encounter at the ages of fifteen with a terrifying alien race, Wyatt, Cody, Duke and Otis are scarred by the death of their friend. Released from experimentation by the creatures, they go their separate ways. Fifteen years later, Cody, Duke and Otis have reunited; ardent in that revenge is the path to take. Wyatt, however, has ultimately decided to live with the past and has chosen a normal life with his wife Hope. Entwined to the fate of Duke, Cody and Otis when they manage to track down and capture a lone alien, Wyatt and Hope are now thrust into a new world of terror as the horrifying abilities of the creature become known. From hypnotizing Hope with a mere glance into her eyes to infecting Cody with a seemingly transmogrification-bound alien virus, the creature is out to wreak havoc upon its captors in any and all of its devious and insidious means.

**Trailer**:

Comment: Yup, that was it, nice one! The trailer was so uneventful I had to search around for images. Found the one with the burnt body, though it wasn't what I thought... ([spoiler](http://liferthemoviecorner.blogspot.co.il/2010/08/altered.html)).

Comment: Great to hear that was the one you were looking for! And thank you for accepting the answer :)